# Finding $[T]_B$, given the inductive construction of $B$ using $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and let $0\neq v\in V$.
>
> Let $T\in\text{Hom}(V,V)$, and construct a basis $B$ with the following rule:
>
> $v_1=v$, and for $i=2,\dots k$, $v_i=T^{i-1}v$.
>
> Given $T^k=I$, find $[T]_B$.

I don't really have a clue what to do. I was able to show that $Tv_i=T^iv$ for all $i=1,\dots n$, so $[Tv_i]_B=[T]_B^i[v]_B$ but that doesn't really help. I guess we should conclude something about $T$ from $B$ being a basis, but what can we even conclude?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a doubt: if you consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $v=(1,0)\neq \overrightarrow{0}$ and the transformation given by $T(x)=Ax$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}=(0,0)$, but $B=\{(1,0),(0,0)\}$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there an hypothesis missing in your problem?

Comment: I think it is given that $B$ is a basis of $V$, hence $T$ is restricted a little more than you thought. Moreover, $T^2\neq I$.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. I thought $T^2=I$ in my case but it clearly is not.

Comment: $[T]_B$ is the companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial. Which is $x^k-1$ ?

Comment: This question revolves linear maps. We didn't get to study eigen-everything yet. (We did learn about matrix similaritiy though if it comes to play in here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $B=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}=\{T^i(v):i=0,1,\ldots,k-1\}$ is a basis of $V$, then we have that columns of $A=[T]_B$ are the representations of the vectors $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_k)$ in the basis $B$. Notice that:

\begin{align*}
T(v_1)=v_2 &\Rightarrow [T(v_1)]_B=(0,1,0,\ldots,0,0)\\
T(v_2)=v_3 &\Rightarrow [T(v_2)]_B=(0,0,1,\ldots,0,0)\\
\vdots & \hspace{1cm}\vdots \hspace{1cm}\vdots\\
T(v_{k-1})=v_k &\Rightarrow [T(v_{k-1}]_B=(0,0,\ldots,1,0)\\
T(v_k)=v_1 &\Rightarrow [T(v_k)]_B=(1,0,0\ldots,0,0)
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
[T]_B&=\big[ [T(v_1)]_B \big| [T(v_2)]_B \big| \cdots \big| [T(v_{k-1})]_B \big| [T(v_k)]_B \big]\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & \ddots & 0 & 0\\ \vdots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}